Dozzle nginx proxy
this is my dozzle-compose.yml file
version: "3"
services:
  dozzle:
    container_name: dozzle
    image: amir20/dozzle:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
#      - ./data:/data
#      - ./index.html:/usr/share/dozzle/index.html
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
#      DOZZLE_AUTH_PROVIDER: simple
      DOZZLE_ENABLE_ACTIONS: true

I am trying to bring dozzle behind nginx
below is my ngonx.conf for dozzle
        location /dozzle/ {
            rewrite ^/dozzle(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_cache off;

            sub_filter_types text/html text/css application/javascript;
            sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/dozzle/';
            sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/dozzle/';
            sub_filter '"/api/' '"/dozzle/api/';
            sub_filter_once off;
        }

i am getting 404 error
https://<my:server:ip>/api/releases
but it works correctly if i access he url
https://<my:server:ip>/dozzle/api/releases
can any body help me out...
I actually tried making the request of dozzle go from /api to /dozzle/api in my conf file but did not happened. I even tried adding BASE_PATH = /dozzle but that also did not worked

Did you try:
environment:
  DOZZLE_BASE: /dozzle

and location:
location /dozzle/ {
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    proxy_pass http://logging:8080;
    proxy_redirect     off;
}

This works for me. Sometime using trailing slash (/) in the url of the request (browser) is needed.
